# How to construct the URL of password reset password page in angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have made a page for users to reset their password if they forget it. Users will get an email that will contain the link of reset password page along with reset token.

URL of password page should look like this:

http://localhost:4200/#/resetpassword?code=CfDJ8LBxIxG2Gf5IjZZG9p+g7oDJxTqYPL7OnGSOIblOksnbNniISOo/jKuZ8RkPriLpsCle5VNwVII5O+r9KPmos1WcwmKCB5mMbYeO/tVKxUiqymsEDFjvWEt0X+KfIQlPbe8fvTMtAaB07IG01vwT2UWn+CjEAYwcZgV6eKhPEP21U9lxLxeG8bE6SXMwninNvWI1lf6jm3Ia1MIDikqL9EC033AMIGlnjvEonbxV+Jb

Here are is my route in router module and reset password page ngOnInit() code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'resetpassword?code=/:code', component: ResetpasswordComponent}
];

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    const param = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('code');
    if(param) {
      this.Code = param;
    }
  }
```

I want to know:

1. How can I set this route in my route definition?
2. How will I read the value of code after code= in ngOnInit of reset password page ?

Anyone who can guide me how can I build a route like this and read the params value?

Comment: {path: 'resetpassword', component: ResetpasswordComponent}

link should be just like you just wrote.

Comment: Just asked out of curiosity, did this strategy worked in production?

Comment: Yes. the accepted answer worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

path should be:

```
{path: 'resetpassword', component: ResetpasswordComponent}
```

navigation:

```
<a
    routerLink="/resetpassword"
    [queryParams]="{code: 'CfDJ8LBxIxG2Gf5IjZZG9p+g7oDJxTqYPL7OnGSOIblOksnbNniISOo/jKuZ8RkPriLpsCle5VNwVII5O+r9KPmos1WcwmKCB5mMbYeO/tVKxUiqymsEDFjvWEt0X+KfIQlPbe8fvTMtAaB07IG01vwT2UWn+CjEAYwcZgV6eKhPEP21U9lxLxeG8bE6SXMwninNvWI1lf6jm3Ia1MIDikqL9EC033AMIGlnjvEonbxV+Jb'}"
  >
  </a>
```

in resetPassword component:

```
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    activeRoute.queryParams
      .subscribe((params) => 
        {
          console.log(params)
    });
  }
```

check [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-routes-8jidep).

Comment: I can't have anchor tag for this on my application. This link will be sent to users in email

Comment: it's ok, you can get query params in your resetPassword page.

Comment: try to put url in browser not by navigating it will work either.

Comment: I am checking. I am able to get the parameters in my ngOnInit method.